# Native JPQL returning BigDecimal instead of Long

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

Does hibernate map SQLServer 2008 NUMERIC type to BigDecimal instead of Long?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really mean *this* direction: database-to-entity (reverse engineering with [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html))? Or do you mean entity-to-database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd say a quick look into the [manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-basictypes) answers your question...